# PHP get filesize of imap attachments

Tags: php, email, imap, attachment, filesize

I am reading imap email with PHP and downloading attachments, using the core imap PHP functions. I am also connecting via the imap protocol (not POP). I would like to be able to know the filesize of attachments before I load them into memory, to reduce server resource usage.

For example I want a limit of 5mb per attachment, this way I can discard any attachments that are over the limit, before they consume any server resources. Finding the size of the email might help but the problem with that is I want the limit per attachment, not per email.

`imap_fetchbody()` is loading the attachment, which all works. I could probably read the size of the result of that function but that would mean loading the attachment into memory first.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is an older post, but in case it helps, the difference in size is due to the attachments being base64-encoded, which results in a roughly 33% expansion of the data. From [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501): "[Body size is] A number giving the size of the body in octets. Note that this size is the size in its transfer encoding and not the resulting size after any decoding."

Answer (score 4):

This question is just over 3 years old with no real answer, I'm surprised.

Loading the email structure using [`imap_fetchstructure();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) will reveal all the information you'll need for this task. I will assume you know how to obtain the particular email you want to check before using `imap_fetchstructure();`.

Anyway, the function will return a list of "parts". These parts are of the IMAP4 specification. The results are given in an array, and one of the array indices is called `bytes` which indicates the number of bytes for that part. There is another index called `encoding` which indicates the method of encoding for that part.

As Paul answered, Base64 encoding is generally about 33% larger than the original size which should be good enough to determine the original data length of the attachment.

I believe you can avoid the hassle of loading the data to memory by writing the data directly to a file handle by the use of the [`imap_savebody();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-savebody.php) function. You can overcome the encoding issue by adding a stream filter to that file handle before calling `imap_savebody();`. This is achieved by the [`stream_filter_append();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-append.php) function.

I may edit my answer and add some working PHP code when I have more time.

Comment: Excellent thanks useful, yes all info you need is in the structure parts portion. For me it was a StdClass but might be case specific. The other answer doesnt answer the question.